# SQL Group By returns multiple rows for the same grouping key

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I have a fact table and a related dimension table. The dimension table has an auto-incrementing primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DimRefund]
(
    [RefundKey]          INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    ... 
    PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([RefundKey]) NOT ENFORCED
)
WITH (
    CLUSTERED INDEX([RefundKey]), 
    DISTRIBUTION = REPLICATE
);
```

The fact table combines keys from different dimension tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FactCash](
    [RefundKey]  [INT] NOT NULL,
    [ClientKey] [INT] NOT NULL,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED  ([RefundKey]) NOT ENFORCED
)               

  WITH
(
    DISTRIBUTION = HASH([RefundKey]),
    CLUSTERED INDEX ([RefundKey])
);
```

I want to test the (incorrect) assumption that `RefundKey` is unique in the fact table, so I ran this query:

```
SELECT RefundKey, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM FactCash
WHERE RefundKey = 153024
GROUP BY RefundKey
```

And got this unexpected result:

| RefundKey | cnt |
| --- | --- |
| 153024 | 1 |
| 153024 | 1 |

If I cast the integer key to a varchar, I get the correct result:

```
SELECT CAST(RefundKey AS VARCHAR(50)) AS RefundKey, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM FactCash
WHERE CAST(RefundKey AS VARCHAR(50)) = 153024
GROUP BY CAST(RefundKey AS VARCHAR(50))
```

| RefundKey | cnt |
| --- | --- |
| 153024 | 2 |

If I try grouping by a different key column, I get the expected result, for example:

```
SELECT TOP 2 ClientKey, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM FactCash
GROUP BY ClientKey
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

| ClientKey | cnt |
| --- | --- |
| 96236 | 4 |
| 90070 | 8 |

What would cause an integer column to group incorrectly like this? I understand if it was a character column with extra whitespace or hidden characters, but an integer should not have hidden characters. Could the incorrect assignment of this column as a primary key on the fact table cause it to group like this?

Comment: Please show the full definition of the table. Try `DBCC CHECKTABLE` just in case there is corruption.

Comment: What's the datatype of the 'RefundKey' field?

Comment: RefundKey is an INT.  `DBCC CHECKTABLE` didn't find any corruption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Queries which you provided in the question, Creating two tables and retrieving data from one table by applying `GROUP BY`. Two tables consists of `PRIMARY KEY` means the data must be unique but in the result it shows the data is not unique, output shows that count of `RefundKey` is `2` even-though the column is `PRIMARY KEY`. It is clearly shown in this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-table-constraints) as primary key is only supported when NONCLUSTERED and NOT ENFORCED are both used and also UNIQUE constraint is only supported when NOT ENFORCED is used.

**GROUP BY** works well even the data type is an `INT` or `VARCHAR`, without applying any `CAST` function as you can see in the below query.

```sql
SELECT Id, COUNT(*) AS Cnt FROM TABLE_A WHERE Id = 1 GROUP BY Id;
```

`TABLE_A` is the sample table which stored `Id` data type as `INT` and while applying `GROUP BY` it produces correct result as you can see in the output below.

```js
Id  Cnt
1   3
```

For more information on GROUP BY, refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#Overview).

Comment: I do think the problem is coming from the incorrect designation of 'primary key' in the fact table, but that's still not explaining why I'm getting weird 'group by' results

Comment: The first document you shared shows an example of how this behavior come from violating the 'unique' constraint explicit in the table. Removing the 'primary key' constraint gave correct 'group by' results.